# How to Send an image to another user of app in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows phone app where two users can exchange text messages and images. I am able to send the text messages through pushnotification platform. But I didn't find a way to send the images.

Is that also possible to send the image files in toast notifications ? Or do we need to user a different concept to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send anything in [Raw Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx) (encode image/file with base64 and include into notification). However I don't think that this idea is good for the messaging.

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented as follows.

When a user sends an image.

1. Store the image on the server side
2. Only send a notification to the other user that they have received an image.
3. On tapping the toast notification

   - Launch the app
   - Download the image from the server.
   - Display the image.